# Geometry nodes join vertex

Tags: node-editor, vertices, geometry-nodes

Is there a way to join two vertices using geometry nodes? I have a few points which I have converted to vertices and I want to join them to create a link of sorts.

Comment: You mean weld points? Please provide more information about what you want achieve

Comment: Do you mean that you want to *connect* loose points, or is it something else that you are after?

Comment: If you want to connect points [the Set Position method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239516/obtain-position-of-point-in-geometry-node/245332#245332) is the only way AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

As Harisreedhar commented correctly, it is not clear what you want. Maybe this helps you? you can delete vertices like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could merge two vertices like so:

[image]

[image]