# Join points / vertices with a line or curve following an arbitrary given index sequence

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertices

How can I join points / vertices with a line or curve following an **arbitrary** given index sequence.

I can have it follow the numerical index sequence **0-1-2-3**

See image below.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

**Example:** I would like to join the vertices following the **arbitrary** index sequence of **0-7-5-4** together with a line see image below.  (**the index sequence is arbitrary** and could be **0-3-7** I would like to be able to have it follow a index sequence I create.)

[image: img3]

I was following [Obtain position of point in geometry node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239516/obtain-position-of-point-in-geometry-node)

and [Where is Transfer attribute in 3.4?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276087/where-is-transfer-attribute-in-3-4)

and [Selectively join points using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253173/selectively-join-points-using-geometry-nodes)

PS  I'm using Blender 3.6.1
Attached file below

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to figure a way to provide a list to Geometry Nodes, here's some threads about it:

[Geometry Nodes - Extrude edge by ID](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/277610/60486)

[How to instantiate objects on individual/selected points in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/249570/60486)

[Cycling /looping through a set of index values using geometry nodes to create animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/274666/60486)

[How can I rotate individual curve points in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/275939/60486)

Then just use that to create a mapping from consecutive indices $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5…$ to the correct indices to know which point positions to sample:

[image]