# Geometry Nodes - saving an integer variable for reuse

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have an integer value I have created from nodes I want to use in multiple places in my project. My thought was to calculate it once then make it available as an integer to the other areas that need it.

I cannot figure out how to do this.  I can put it in a node group and reuse that, but this surely means it will need to be evaluated from scratch every time it is used.

Is there a way to do this.  I only want to store 1 integer (at this point) for the whole of the node tree.

Answer (score 1):

Create an **mesh** object, set its visibility options so it's convenient (for enable axes visibility, so that even if it contains just one point, it can still be easily selectable):

[image]

Perhaps add it to some collection to ensure it won't be rendered and to easily hide it together with similar objects:

[image]

Consider also moving such objects to one place where they are easily selectable and don't distract when working on real geometry…

Then add a geonodes modifier like so:

[image]

I'm using *Set ID* to store the integer, so that I don't waste memory on adding a new attribute. If you want to store more integers, rather than increasing the *Count* of the *Points* node (which could be useful if you calculate the integer values based on index in a field), consider just adding multiple *Points* nodes and joining them like I did [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/298116/60486):

[image]

Above I was actually storing floats as radii of the points, and similarly you could store vectors as their positions. This saves a little bit of memory, but those are completely insignificant savings in 99.999% of cases… On the other hand, both radius and position affect the bounding box of the object, which can be very distracting, so consider using *Store Named Attribute* instead.

Once you have your object, you can access your data in any other geonodes tree:

[image]

If you used *Store Named Attribute*, then here instead of *ID* use *Named Attribute*.

If you want to access the data outside of geometry nodes, see:

[Passing GeoNodes attribute to Shader frame offset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/265282/60486)